# Adding Script for Comment Box in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am building a website in drupal. I want the users to add comment using google transliterate. I have the code for that but I am not getting how i can attach the script to the comment box.

I am using the Google Transliterate API. When a user types a word in Hindi (in English) in the comment box of drupal it should automatically change to that language,as in example Hindi

Can give some suggestions?

Comment: What code you have? What it does? How do you want to use it with your Drupal website?

Comment: Check this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/googlelanguageapi, if that helps you.